# "No servers found" using openid light

Tags: php, authentication, openid, lightopenid

All of a sudden i'm getting this error message using Light Open ID.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'No servers found!' in /home/a3422801/public_html/LoginAssignment/php/openid.php:463 Stack trace: #0 /home/a3422801/public_html/LoginAssignment/php/openid.php(595): LightOpenID->discover() #1 /home/a3422801/public_html/LoginAssignment/index.php(9): LightOpenID->authUrl() #2 {main} thrown in /home/a3422801/public_html/LoginAssignment/php/openid.php on line 463

...and the small snippet of relevant code in `openid.php`:

```
if ($server) {
                # We found an OpenID2 OP Endpoint
                if ($delegate) {
                    # We have also found an OP-Local ID.
                    $this->identity = $delegate;
                }
                $this->server = $server;
                return $server;
            }

            throw new ErrorException('No servers found!');
```

I have no idea what the problem is - this is a recent issue. Does anyone know has something changed recently with OpenID. I'll gladly provide any more code that is required. I'm new with logins and PHP in general so i apologize if this is very vague.

This google login is coupled with a FB login if this has any bearing - but like i said, this was functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by comparing the OpenID URL I was using, with the one here on StackOverflow. Turns out I wasn't using **https**. Until recently, this was not a problem, but now it seems to be required.

So make sure you're using the following URL:
**https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id**

After changing this, it works again at my websites.